# Case-insensitive add_rewrite_rules in Wordpress functions

Tags: rewrite-rules

Been hitting my head against the wall on this for a while.  If I have a add_rewrite_rules like so:

```
    $aNewRules = array('my-books/?$'  => 'index.php?pagename=my-books');
```

This works correctly; going to http://example.com/my-books/ shows http://example.com/index.php?pagename=my-books.

However, this is case sensitive - going to "/My-bOoKs/" does not trip the rule (and thus shows the 404 page instead).

Is there an easy way to just mark it as case insensitive?  I only make links with the lower case, sure, but users may add a capital on their own and I'd hate to lose the traffic to a 404 page.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: If you want to achieve such thing you'll have to add a rewrite rule for each assumption e.g `My-bOoKs, My-books, etc ..` but the perfect solution here I guess is to redirect those to the normal `pagename` 'my-books'..

Comment: @SamuelElh - At that point, I could do something more like '[Mm][Yy]-[Bb][Oo][Oo][Kk][Ss]/?$' . . . but I have a lot of these rules in place, so I'd like something a bit less tedious of possible :).

Comment: That totally does it! why not implement that one?

Comment: Just because it's messy and tedious - if there's no other way, I'll do that, but I was hoping there's a simple tag (like '?i' or something) I could add to do that instead - I've found a number of things online with [NC] or some "i" related tag that is meant to do this in Regex, just can't get any of them to work in Wordpress at this level :).

Comment: Makes sense. You could do `'([^/]+)/?$', ...&my_books_check=$matches[1]` and later check with `get_query_var('my_books_check')`, lowercase it, if `=== "my-books"` then redirect to `my-books` (assuming a part was lowercase), if `!== "my-books"` then filter `$wp_query` and set `is_404`.. That would result in a lot of work unlike the redirect.. Hope someone else gives a good solution for this.

Comment: Haha, yeah - I'd rather just use the brackets :D

Answer (score 2):

As the answer below mentions, it is not possible to pass a flag to `add_rewrite_rule()`; however, it *is* possible to use an inline modifier. In your example, you would do this:

`$aNewRules = array('(?i)my-books/?$'  => 'index.php?pagename=my-books');`

(note the `(?i)` in the regular expression).

The advantage of this approach is that your rewrite rules are much cleaner and more performant.

See [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) on regular expression modifiers for more information.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks Eric!

Answer (score -1):

Not directly.  The wordpress API is using preg_match / preg_replace but is not exposing the flags parameter.  That's what you'd need to pass the insensitive flag (i).

See their implementation here:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/a8802232ecac8184cbe6e8dbe9c6a7bd0f5b7dee/wp-includes/class-wp-rewrite.php

Probably the simplest solution is just to use a little helper function to do this for you:

```
function anyCase($rules){
    $insensitive = array();
    foreach ($rules as $regex => $mapping) {
      $regex = preg_replace_callback('([A-Za-z])', function($matches){
            return "[" . strtoupper($matches[1]) . strtolower($matches[1]) . "]";
      }, $regex);
      $insensitive[$regex] = $mapping;
    }
    return $insensitive;
  }
```

Given

```
$rules = array('my-books/?$'  => 'index.php?pagename=my-books');
var_dump(anyCase($rules));
```

Will output
    array(1) { ["[Mm][Yy]-[Bb][Oo][Oo][Kk][Ss]/?$"]=> string(27) "index.php?pagename=my-books" }

So you can keep your rules clean / simple :-)

If you're running an older PHP that doesn't support closures you can just this instead:

```
  function lowerOrUpper($matches){
    return "[" . strtoupper($matches[0]) . strtolower($matches[0]) . "]";
  }

  function anyCase($rules){
    $insensitive = array();
    foreach ($rules as $regex => $mapping) {
      $regex = preg_replace_callback('([A-Za-z])', lowerOrUpper, $regex);
      $insensitive[$regex] = $mapping;
    }
    return $insensitive;
  }
```

Cheers

Comment: I ended up down this path, but after some research, I found what I think is a better solution (using inline regex modifiers). Hope it helps!